# lighttpd mod_redirect https to http specifically for media file types

Tags: redirect, lighttpd

I have a lighttpd 1.4.26 (ssl) configuration on a cent-os linux machine serving an HTML5 media application over HTTPS.

My goal is to serve media files via the application over HTTP from the same webserver.

If the webserver were located at https://www.media.com/ and all the media is located in various subfolders of http://www.media.com/sharedmedia/XXXXX, and I have relative links to any media file in the html for the pages served over http, then I want all requests to .mp3, .mp4, .webm, and .ogv files to be redirected to the EXACT SAME URL but using http instead of https...

My problem is I do not know how to write a url.redirect rule to perform this translation...

I have tried:

```
url.redirect = ( "https://^(.*)\.(ogv|mp4|mp3|webm)$" => "http://%1/$1" )
```

And when I visit this URL:

```
https://www.media.com/sharedmedia/X-MAC-MINI/Sports/Amazing%20Football%20Skills%20and%20Tricks.ogv
```

I am 301 permanently redirected to

```
http://www.media.com/sharedmedia/X-MAC-MINI/Sports/Amazing0Football0Skills0and0Tricks.ogv
```

Which is then also 301'ed to:

```
http:///sharedmedia/AFFINEGY-MAC-MINI/Sports/Amazing0Football0Skills0and0Tricks
```

Notice that the %20's that were in the very first url (urlencoded SPACE) were dropped from the URL leaving the trailing '0' in each case during the first redirect (I assume interpreted as %2 which holds an empty string), and that the http request is ALSO redirected erroniously to another URL that doesn't even contain the host value (www.media.com). Also, the extension is left off the second redirect...

I then tried a conditional version after that:

```
$HTTP["socket"] =~ ":443$"
{
url.redirect = ( "^(.*)\.(ogv|mp4|mp3|webm)$" => "http://%1/$1" )
}
```

..which results in lighttpd simply crashing on startup, so I can't even test it. Lighttpd startup error message follows:

```
Starting lighttpd: 2011-08-31 16:19:15: (configfile.c.907) source: find /etc/lighttpd/conf.d -maxdepth 1 -name '*.conf' -exec cat {} \; line: 44 pos: 1 parser failed somehow near here: (EOL)
2011-08-31 16:19:15: (configfile.c.907) source: /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf line: 331 pos: 1 parser failed somehow near here: (EOL)
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did wrong:

You need a nested "IF" to use the %n notation in the destination IP rule...

I had

```
$HTTP["socket"] =~ ":443$"
{
url.redirect = ( "^(.*)\.(ogv|mp4|mp3|webm)$" => "http://%1/$1" )
}
```

But I needed

```
$HTTP["socket"] =~ ":443$" {
 $HTTP["host"] == (.*) {
 url.redirect = ( "^(.*)\.(ogv|mp4|mp3|webm)$" => "http://%1/$1.$2" )
 }
}
```

Now... the %1 in "http://%1/$1" refers to the match in "$HTTP["host"] == (.*)" while $1 refers to the match in the url redirect parens, and $2 refers to the match for the second set of parens in the url redirect source...

Is it just me or is this shit TOTALLY undocumented? I can only find on google people complaining of not being able to get this to work and no one seems to have a single answer for how it works...

I'm now stuck making the EXACT same thing happen in APACHE, and I can't find a good documentation on .htaccess 301 redirects for it either...